# handle multiple research articles with langchain text splitters

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I have a basic questions regarding langchain text splitters.
I have a list of 1000 abstracts.
I used langchain RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter.create_documents() method to chunk the text.
The output of this gives me about, let say, 1005 documents.
Shouldn't we expect the length of the document to be same as 1000.
Because, if we run some function on these document, let say summarization, i need to be able to connect the summary with the original 1000 abstracts.
I don't have a clue, how to really connect langchain based results back to original document to make some insights.

On top of the text splitters, if i use a vector db such as the chroma, i am getting different size. This makes it difficult to use the result properly.
Can anyone suggest, if I am missing something?
Thanks